# FireStore REST API: How to add a subcollection to a document using REST commands?

Tags: rest, collections, google-cloud-firestore

Using FireStore's REST API documented at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest

I'm trying to create a new document in "**users**" that has a subcollection named "**subcol1**" with an empty doc in it called "**subdoc1**"

However, the following REST command to create the new document does not work:

```
curl -X POST 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d "{ 'fields': { 'subcol1': [{'subdoc1': { 'fields': {} } }] } }"
"https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/XXXX/databases/(default)/documents/users"
```

How does one add a subcollection to a new document (or existing one?) using FireStore's REST API?

I specifically have to use REST for this implementation.

This is the error response I get back:

```
{   "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid value at 'document.fields[0].value' (Map), Cannot have repeated items ('subcol1') within a map.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"\" at 'document.fields[0].value': Proto fields must have a name.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "document.fields[0].value",
            "description": "Invalid value at 'document.fields[0].value' (Map), Cannot have repeated items ('subcol1') within a map."
          },
          {
            "field": "document.fields[0].value",
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"\" at 'document.fields[0].value': Proto fields must have a name."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]   } }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After more tinkering with this, I found a solution.

The following works:

1. First create the new document (without the subcollection).
2. Next create the subdocument using the "not-yet-created" subcollection's URL.

**So first create the new "top-level" doc:**

```
curl -X POST 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d "{ 'fields': { } }"
"https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/XXXX/databases/(default)/documents/users"
```

**Then create the subdoc (which "creates" the subcollection):**

```
curl -X POST 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d "{ 'fields': { } }"
"https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/XXXX/databases/(default)/documents/
users/<USER-KEY-FROM-PREVIOUS-JSON-RESPONSE>/subcol1"
```

Comment: I don't think you should have to create the "top-level" document if it doesn't have to contain any data.  The SDKs don't require you to do this.  You can have a subcollection organized under a nonexisting document.  It will show up in the console in italics, and you can click through to its subcollections.